# C# WebBrowser.ShowPrintDialog() not showing

Tags: c#, html, printing

I have this peculiar problem while wanting to print a html-report. The file itself is a normal  local html file, located on my hard drive.

To do this, I have tried the following:

```
    public static void PrintReport(string path)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.Navigate(path);
        wb.ShowPrintDialog()
    }
```

And I have this form with a button with the click event:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"D:\MyReport.html";
        PrintReport(path);
    }
```

This does absolutely nothing. Which is kind of strange... but things get stranger...

When editing the print function to do the following:

```
    public static void PrintReport(string path)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.Navigate(path);
        MessageBox.Show("TEST");
        wb.ShowPrintDialog()
    }
```

It works. Yes, only adding a MessageBox. The MessageBox is showing and after it comes the print dialog. I have also tried with Thread.Sleep(1000) instead, which doesn't work. Can anyone explain to me what's going on here? Why would a messagebox make any difference?

Can it be some kind of permission problem? I've reproduced this on both Windows 7 and 8, same thing. I made this small application with only the above code to isolate the problem. I am quite sure it works on windows XP though, since an older version of the application I'm working on runs on it. When trying to do this directly with the mshtml-dll instead I also get problems.

Any input or clarification is greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you know how can i change paper size (C5) and orientation (Landscape) before printing programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the browser is not ready to print yet.  You will want to add an event handler WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler to the WebBrowser Object.  Sample code below.

```
public static void PrintReport(string path)
{
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
    wb.Navigate(path);
}

public static void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
    if (wb.ReadyState.Equals(WebBrowserReadyState.Complete))
        wb.ShowPrintDialog();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Could you or someone explain this a bit further to me so I also learn a bit more? To me this looks like a document will always be printed when the even "Document completed" occurs? This seems a bit odd to me in general, but I'm sure it's lack of understanding. The actual event I want to trigger the print dialog is a button click or something similar. What if I would use the webbrowser object to navigate to another document that I didn't want to print? Thank you again for pointing out the problem, it was driving me insane.

Comment: @jeah_wicer Glad I could Help, Dont forget to mark it as answered!   As to your question; If you assign the event handler then you are correct every document will print once it has completed loading.  One suggestion is that you can resolve this by using a bool to flag if the document should be printed.  There are several ways to overcome the not printing every document once it has completed loading.  It really depends on what you are doing in your project.

Comment: Thanks again! I will mark this as solved, but what I really would like to solve first in order for this to be useful both for me and others is how to make a generic print-html function without altering the standard functionality of the object. If this event is added the object starts to behave differently and I want to believe that there is a easier, nicer and more straight-forward way of printing a html document? Is it not possible to implement a print function that waits for the url to finish loading and then opens up the print dialog? Rather than printing in the actual event.

Comment: I have studied how events work and admit I didn't have much knowledge about how they work. After looking at the very same example as the one you provided but here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) instead, I realized just by different naming that the created function (PrintDocument in the provided link) of course is specified at what you're doing and not generic. It was just my lack of understanding the events structure. Thanks again!