# Webrowser1.ShowPrintDialog() not showing on windows 7 but does in Windows 10

Tags: vb.net

I am having an odd issue with a simple line of code not executing in a Windows 7 environment that has .NET 4.5 installed on it.

I have this code below. It should show the print dialog after the webrowser loads an html document generated after clicking a button. All that works, the file is created, but on a Windows 7 machine the dialog does not show. On Windows 10 it does. Further testing I added a button that when clicked should show the dialog. Same result, shows on Windows 10, but not on Windows 7

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        WebBrowser1.ShowPrintDialog()
End Sub
```

Is there some odd option that might be suppressing the print dialog that I am not aware of, or could this be an actual issue with my code?

Comment: Add a breakpoint on the line - is it being executed and just simply ignored? Or is your parent event not firing?

Comment: It is being executed, but nothing happens

Comment: This addressed a similar issue but used C#. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827317/c-sharp-webbrowser-showprintdialog-not-showing